# RavenDB Import / Export failing on Server but working on Embedded

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-http

I am looking at writing an import / export routine for RavenDB so that I can develop on a full server instance locally but can run embedded on the website due to resource contraints. I want to be able to admin functions in a locked down section of the site to allow for backups and restores from files. But I also want to be able to restore a production data set into a local server instance for debugging and development purposes.

As part of this I have been investigating using v2.5.2750 the ISmugglerApi interface and specifically the Raven.Database.Smuggler.DataDumper and the Raven.Smuggler.SmugglerApi implementations.

I can backup and restore using an Embedded instance fine. I can backup the server instance fine and import this file into the Embedded instance. However restoring into the Server database is where the issue occurs.

The code which I am using is as follows:

Restore code:

```
        SmugglerOptions smugglerOptions = new SmugglerOptions { BackupPath = Server.MapPath(ServerMapPath) };
        switch (Context)
        {
            case Context.Embedded:
                DataDumper dumper = new DataDumper(((EmbeddableDocumentStore)MvcApplication.Store).DocumentDatabase, smugglerOptions);
                var embeddedImport = dumper.ImportData(smugglerOptions);
                await embeddedImport;
                break;

            case Context.Server:
                var connectionStringOptions = new RavenConnectionStringOptions
                {
                    ApiKey = Configuration.ApiKey,
                    DefaultDatabase = Configuration.DefaultDatabase,
                    Url = Configuration.DefaultUrl
                };

                var smugglerApi = new SmugglerApi(smugglerOptions, connectionStringOptions);
                var serverImport = smugglerApi.ImportData(smugglerOptions);
                await serverImport;
                break;
        }
```

Backup code:

```
        SmugglerOptions smugglerOptions = new SmugglerOptions { BackupPath = Server.MapPath(ServerMapPath) };
        switch (Context)
        {
            case Context.Embedded:
                DataDumper dumper = new DataDumper(((EmbeddableDocumentStore)MvcApplication.Store).DocumentDatabase, smugglerOptions);
                var embeddedExport = dumper.ExportData(null, smugglerOptions, false);
                await embeddedExport;
                break;

            case Context.Server:
                var connectionStringOptions = new RavenConnectionStringOptions
                {
                    ApiKey = Configuration.ApiKey,
                    DefaultDatabase = Configuration.DefaultDatabase,
                    Url = Configuration.DefaultUrl
                };

                var smugglerApi = new SmugglerApi(smugglerOptions, connectionStringOptions);
                var serverExport = smugglerApi.ExportData(null, smugglerOptions, false);
                await serverExport;
                break;
        }
```

ServerMapPath is currently a const string for the name of the file which is in the App_Data folder.

The Configuration.* is a simple static class to read out the values from the web.config for the required settings.

Context is a configuration option to specify the type of environment which this is running in.

When I run the restore into the Server database configuration I get the following:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>
> [WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad
>   Request.]    System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6592536
>   Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadJsonInternal(Func`1
>   getResponse) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:349
>
> [InvalidOperationException:
>
> ## Could not figure out
>   what to do
>
> Your request didn't match anything that Raven
>   knows to do, sorry...
>
> ]
>   Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.HandleErrors(WebException e)
>   in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:513
>   Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadJsonInternal(Func`1
>   getResponse) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:355
>   Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseJson() in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:239
>   Raven.Client.Document.RemoteBulkInsertOperation.GetAuthToken() in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\RemoteBulkInsertOperation.cs:151
>   Raven.Client.Document.d_*b.MoveNext() in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\RemoteBulkInsertOperation.cs:0
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52
>
>   Raven.Client.Document.d*_3.MoveNext() in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\RemoteBulkInsertOperation.cs:100
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    Raven.Client.Document.d__18.MoveNext() in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\RemoteBulkInsertOperation.cs:281
>
> [AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +83
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +71    Raven.Smuggler.d_*6.MoveNext() in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Smuggler\SmugglerApi.cs:87
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    Raven.Abstractions.Smuggler.d*_26.MoveNext()
>   in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Abstractions\Smuggler\SmugglerApiBase.cs:322
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +21    SampleApplication.Controllers.d__15.MoveNext() in c:\Src\Random\RavenImportExport\SampleApplication\Controllers\HomeController.cs:105
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    lambda_method(Closure , Task ) +23
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task)
>   +33    System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +68
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass34.b*_33(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +16
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b_*3c()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass45.b_*3e()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass30.b_*2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass28.b_*19()
>   +26    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass1e.b_*1b(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b*_1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b_*15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +28
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b*_4(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +31    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +129

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the same version of smuggler & ravendb server?
Try tunneling this through fiddler, and see what the responses looks like

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and pointers. I had updated the packages but I hadn't repointed the service and restarted it! Once I had done this the import into the server version works fine. Cheers